# Inactive folder in remote repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I committed and pushed the content of a local folder to the remote .git repository. As a result I expected to get two sub-folders. However, one of sub-folders looks inaccessible for some reason (see the picture).
[image]
Why does it happen? The content of FizzBuzz is pretty simple - just a single .py file.

Comment: It appears to my that this is another repo in your repo.

Comment: @zaratustra: This makes sense. Let me check.